# Python script to get execution time using "time"

Tags: python, time

I need my script to execute a binary file a number of times and get some statistics about its execution time using the the "time" directive. However the following code crashes:

```
cmd = ["time", "./executable", "<", "input_file"]
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

with the following message:

File "exec_script.py", line 15, in 
    result = subprocess.Popen("time ./quake < small_input", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have been cracking my skull for hours now and can't figure this out, any help? Note that if I just run that command from the same directory, it works. But not through the script.

Comment: You need `shell=True` to use features such as input redirection.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks! Can you help me as to why out = result.stdout.read() is "Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]" ?

Comment: I'm not sure but try using a single string instead of a list.